# ClosedRange Firebase Swift read & write

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, range

I am using a Closed range e.g let ageRange = ClosedRange(18...45)

What is the best way of saving this to Firebase DB? Do I need to save the lower and upper bound separately?

Thanks

Comment: Firebase is a broad platform of products. What specific Firebase product are you trying to store this data in?

Comment: Hey, Firebase Database

Comment: Yes, probably easiest to save the lower and upper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase Database can only store JSON types.

Since `ClosedRange` is not a JSON type, you'll have to find a way to convert it back and forth.

Two common ways to do this:

1. Store it as a single string
2. Store its constituent parts

The first one is often easiest. But the second option has the advantage that you can query for its parts.